# Dynamically provide Aurelia view model instance

Tags: aurelia

I'm looking for a way to dynamically provide at runtime view models for any views. Question is if there is hook in the ViewEngine or a view model loader / factory that I can use to do this.

I'm looking into bridging into WebAssembly and allowing view models to be written in other languages and I want to create automatic interop view models on the Javascript side for Aurelia to just work.

Comment: the [`compose`](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/dynamic-ui-composition#basic-composition) element is exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm looking to do this as a hook dynamically - not declaratively. So basically hook into Aurelia and provide the view model as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally doable, and many have successfully delivered their ultra-dynamic application using Aurelia, as pretty much everything in Aurelia is dynamic.

For example:

- dynamic, instance based inline view: https://codesandbox.io/s/r0no20706p (Based on this discourse topic https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/template-literals-in-class-instance/1829/6)
- dynamic, remote view strategy: https://codesandbox.io/s/8ljmrq3vql (Based on a github question)
- dynamic, route based view model: https://codesandbox.io/s/ywyj60p9qj (based on this discourse https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/ideas-on-data-driven-ui-composition-vs-previous-angularjs-approach/2269/3

Basically it boils down to is to use `.compose` method from `CompositionEngine`:

```
compositionEngine.compose({
  viewModel:
    string // as module path
    | Function // as constructor
    | object // as instance
})
```

And make sure the view is resolvable from the view model.